# use remote image uri in react-native-maps MapView

Tags: image, react-native, uri, react-native-maps

I'm using react-native-maps for my react-native application. I need to post image on the MapView on the map. But, I get image from web. Whereas, as I know only local images can be added to Mapview in react-native-maps. Do you know any way to post image from `uri` in the `react-native-maps MapView`?

I tried with

```
<MapView style={{flex: 1}}
                loadingEnabled={true}
                region={this.state.region}
                onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChangeComplete}>

               <MapView.Marker
                    coordinate={{latitude: this.props.user_location[0], longitude: this.props.user_location[1]}}
                    title={this.props.user_name}
                    description={this.props.user_desc}>
                   <Image source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}} />
               </MapView.Marker>

            </MapView>
```

and the result is

[image]

And then I just deleted the `<Image/>` with

```
<MapView style={{flex: 1}}
                loadingEnabled={true}
                region={this.state.region}
                onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChangeComplete}>

               <MapView.Marker
                    coordinate={{latitude: this.props.user_location[0], longitude: this.props.user_location[1]}}
                    title={this.props.user_name}
                    description={this.props.user_desc}>
               </MapView.Marker>

            </MapView>
```

and the result is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can try  [custom marker view](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/README.md#rendering-a-marker-with-a-custom-view)

```
<MapView.Marker coordinate={marker.latlng}>
  <Image source={{uri: 'http://someCustomImageURL' }} />
</MapView.Marker>
```

Comment: Thanks Man, I updated my question according to your answer.
I tried but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I find out the way.

Actually, I used Native-Base in my application. So, component `Thumbnail` is imported from Native-base.

My code is like

```
<MapView style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between'}}
                loadingEnabled={true}
                region={this.state.region}
                onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChangeComplete}>

               <MapView.Marker
                    coordinate={{latitude: this.props.user_location[0], longitude: this.props.user_location[1]}}
                    title={this.props.user_name}
                    description={this.props.user_desc}>
                    <View>
                        <Thumbnail source={{uri: this.props.user_photo}} />
                    </View>
               </MapView.Marker>

            </MapView>
```